# php-java bridge Error: Could not connect to server

Tags: java, php, apache, jsp, php-java-bridge

I'm trying to set up php-java bridge for the past day and cannot figure out what is not working.

I have Apache2 and Tomcat7 running on Debian

JSP server pages [work fine](http://tx.rxtron.com:8080/test.jsp).
But PHP pages [produce an error](http://tx.rxtron.com:8080/JavaBridge/index.php).

I'm currently operating in `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/JavaBridge` which contains: test.php and WEB-INF

WEB-INF/web.xml contains:

```
<!-- the following 8 lines extend the servlet spec 2.2 "url-pattern" to handle P$
<filter>
    <filter-name>PhpCGIFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>php.java.servlet.PhpCGIFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PhpCGIFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- the following adds the JSR223 listener. Remove it if you don't want to use $
<listener>
    <listener-class>php.java.servlet.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- the back end for external (console, Apache/IIS-) PHP scripts; remove it if $
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>PhpJavaServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>php.java.servlet.PhpJavaServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<!-- runs PHP scripts in this web app; remove it if you don't need this -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>PhpCGIServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PhpJavaServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.phpjavabridge</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PhpCGIServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.php</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.php</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I do have php-cgi installed and fastcgi installed (php5.fcgi, libapache2-mod-fastcgi)

Why can I not run PHP pages?

Comment: look in /var/lib/tomcat7/logs for any messages in the log files.  See if there was any msg related to config, etc.

Comment: Here's my logs: http://pastebin.com/tTncZT92

Comment: Where is FastCGI server running? 

This doc http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/server/documentation/API/php/java/servlet/fastcgi/FastCGIServlet.html talks about how the FASTCGI server can be started.